# The server encountered an error processing the request

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, model-view-controller

I'm Using `WCF` Restful services with EF 5.
When I want to insert a record into database then it gives me error

```
The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details.
```

For this I have found These solution

[WCF Data Service 5.6 quick start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255201/wcf-data-service-5-6-quick-start)

[The server encountered an error processing the request](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F21803522%2Fthe-server-encountered-an-error-processing-the-request-see-server-logs-for-more&ei=Q1uRVOjrIc21uQTs1oGoAw&usg=AFQjCNHN2hJ0T-XRifK4b88Hd8OtSC69XA&bvm=bv.82001339,d.c2E&cad=rja)

According to this solution I have Changed My code but still getting Same Problem. This Is My Changes Service Class code

```
namespace WcfRestMVC
{
    public class EmployeeService : DataService<DemoContext>, IEmployeeService
    {
        public string AddEmployee(Employee employee)
        {
            if (employee != null)
            {
                return "Records Could not  be added";
            }
            else
            {
                using (DemoContext DbObj = new DemoContext())
                {
                    DbObj.employees.Add(employee);
                    DbObj.SaveChanges();
                    return "Employee Added";
                }
            }
        }
  }
}
```

and My Interface as follow

```
namespace WcfRestMVC
{

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IEmployeeService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "AddEmployee")]
        string AddEmployee(Employee employee);
    }
}
```

This is My Context Class

```
 public class DemoContext:DbContext
    {

        public DbSet<Employee> employees { get; set; }
    }
```

My JS

```
$('#btnAdd').on('click', function () {
            var Fname = $('#txtFname').val();
            var Lname = $('#txtLname').val();
            var Title = $('#txtTitle').val();
            var employeeData = {
                "FirstName": Fname,
                "LastName": Lname,
                "Title": Title
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:53125/EmployeeService.svc/AddEmployee",
                contentType: "json",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(employeeData),
                processData: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#spanAdd').text(data);
                    $('#spanAdd').show();
                    BindData();
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: The solutions you found do not have to be relevant to your problem. The error "The server encountered an error processing the request" can mean _anything_. You need to, also indicated by the message, **check the server logs for details**. The Application log will contain the message of the actual exception.

Comment: This error in other words is saying: "There was an error on server side, please look for problems in server, not client side". So start debugging your EmployeeService and you'll see the actual problem.

Comment: @Reniuz: I have put Debug Point on Add Employee Method of Server Class but It's not getting Called.

Comment: You need to start debugging your server. How you host it?